# Webservice operation not working

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I am working on a web service, which is giving me a peculiar error . When i hit any operation from the SOAP UI, it gives me this error  :

```
[2/26/14 4:46:58:179 EST] 0000006b AxisEngine    E org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive java.lang.InstantiationException: com.raghav.RaghavService
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.raghav.RaghavService
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:242)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:208)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1544)
```

When i start my server(WAS 8.5), i get this error :

`CWNEN0009E: The injection engine failed to process the XML code from the deployment descriptor due to the following error: An injection target for the com.raghav.RaghavService/raghavFacade reference cannot be processed because neither the setRaghavFacade method nor the raghavFacade field exist on the com.raghav.RaghavService class.`

In soap UI , when i try to run an operation i get this error :
`<faultcode>axis2ns1:Server</faultcode>
 <faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>`

**EDIT :**

**RaghavService.java :**

```
package com.raghav.RaghavService;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class RaghavService  {

    @EJB
    RaghavLocal raghavFacade;

    @WebResult(name = "updateMyResponse")
    public MyResponse updateMyResponse(Remit remit) {

        return response;

    }

}
```

I am splitting my hairs here, yet i am unable to understand what is causing this problem . Any help is greatly appreciated .

Comment: post your RadhavService class

Comment: RaghavService -- should contain a reference to raghavFacade.

RaghavService havent had the property reference to set the value while loading the application.

Comment: I am gonna post the service.

Comment: Updated the post with a sample of the service class @VinayVeluri